# SERVICE_PLIST: GoogleService-Info.plist could not be located

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I'm having trouble with Firebase Crash Report.

I created the project and installed Firebase via cocoapods following tutorial.

I implemented the crash report following tutorial.

My Run Script:

```
"${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym "Organizze/Organizze-282b91162d30.json"
```

My Pod File:

```
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Crash'
```

My error:

```
FirebaseCrash/upload-sym:132: error: SERVICE_PLIST: GoogleService-Info.plist could not be located
```

GoogleService-Info.plist is inside the project folder along with the json file.

Error:

[image: 1]

Upload-sym file:

[image: 2]

Comment: Have you added GoogleService-Info.plist in project navigator?

Comment: Yes, GoogleService-Info.plist appear on project navigator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you set the target membership of the file.

1. Select `GoogleService-Info.plist` in the Xcode project navigator.
2. Enable the target in the right utilities pane.

[image]